# Is it possible to send dynamic id constant at runtime through xpath of a webelement?

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver

I tried passing dynamic id constant as parameter getting value at runtime :

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, "+(table_id)+")]/div/table/thead/tr"));
```

Where `table_id` is String variable.

It gives random result..

Why Doesn't give correct result at every test execution?

Comment: <div id="c92f76bb-11f3-532e-instructions"><div class="c92f76bb-11f3-532e-table">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table condensed">
<tbody><tr><td><div class="btn-group"><a data-id="14" class="btn btn-edit btn-small c92f76bb-11f3-532e-edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i> </a></tr></tbody>    I wanted to click an edit link present in a table data. here passing table_id as 'instructions' and try accessing that div which contain result table.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing here table_id is a number - 
You can put it under loop and use driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, "+(table_id)+")]/div/table/tbody/*")); and do the needed operations.

Comment: it would be better if you provide html snippet. thnx.

Comment: Here table_id is String variable pass as a parameter when that function is calling for Example : String table_id = " 'post-tasks' ";

Comment: @ShwetaTetambe it would be better if you provide a snippet of html and let us know what you are trying to achieve, it will help us to help u out. Thanks.

Comment: As far as i can see from your xpath u r trying to get the row of the table...what is the actual data expected and what is the random results u r getting?

Comment: yes.. i am trying to get row.. As the table present in a div has dynamic id and i am passing its constant value at runtime, Sometimes its randomly access some other div where the constant value matches irrespective of differ in full xpath and element expected doesn't match then test script breaks with "No such element found" Error.                                                                Please provide me an alternate solution to get ride of this problem.

Comment: you can use this xpath -- "//a[contains(@class,'" + table_id +"e-edit')]"..this might help u...please have a look...thnaks...
PS here table_id i am supposing is to be 'c92f76bb-11f3-532' which is generated dynamically...but if u are not able to get this id before and need to get first row only u can try out //a[contains(@class,'e-edit')]/.. - '..' accessing parent element that will be tr here.

Comment: No i wanted to access td where link is present in any row of the result-table.

Comment: If u ant to get td use `//a[contains(@class,'e-edit')]/preceeding-sibling::td` and if u want all tds having link under instructions div use `//div[contains(@id,'instructions')]//td[/a[contains(@class,'e-edit')]]`

Answer (score 0):

I am nor sure whether it is typo or you are intended to write the code in that way, i see "class" in your html code, but you are using "id" in your xPath.

I tried below xpath and it is working fine.

```
$x("//div[contains(@class, 'c92f76bb-11f3-532e-table')]/table/tbody/tr/td/div")
```

Please replace id with class and the correct xpath hierarchy

Thanks,
Uday